# Why is my dualboot system asking for "grub"?

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode, grubrescue

I switched on my laptop and it asked me for `grub`. I don't know what that means. I use both Windows and Ubuntu.

This is what it said:

```
GNU GRUB version1.99-12ubuntu5
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Any where else TAB lists possible or file completions.
```

I'm stuck, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Grub was the sofware providing the menu of Windows and Ubuntu and let you select either one. Did this message come out instead?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is going to help, but that screen shows up whenever my bootloader is broken for whatever reason
Don't know how to fix it though, I restore from a system backup